# Ideas on how to store Key-Value pairs in a dynamic array based structure

Tags: c++, g++, placement-new

I have a dynamic array that has the following properties:

1. Stores Key-Value pair structures.
2. Re-allocates memory whenever an entry is added (realloc). Invoke constructor.
3. Deletion is tricky - The entry getting deleted has to be moved from wherever it is to the end of the array - It's contents (The Key and the Value) have to be swapped with the current last item in the array. Invoke destructor. Re-allocate memory so that the entry is deleted.

Now the problem is I originally stored the Value by reference in the Entry. But, I can't use `operator=` then. But I can't store by value either. And I don't want to store pointers because that would defeat the whole purpose. The only option left I see at the moment is to invoke placement new on the entry getting deleted and invoke copy constructor on it from the last element. This would let me keep the Value by reference. Any advice? Or pitfalls I should look out for?

Comment: Have you considered a linked list?  Seems this is a great argument for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why storing by pointers is any different than storing by reference.  You get the advantage of being able to reassign, which you say you need.

1. They take up the same size
2. You are still responsible for keeping the referent alive as long as the container is alive
3. Someone is still responsible for destroying the referent at some point
4. You can keep this choice hidden from the public API

The only advantage of the reference is that it can't be null, but no one is going to access it directly.  You can still use references in the API, so nulls can't be passed in.

Comment: The difference is a reference is a const pointer. It can't be reseated. However, I found the answer for my question. It seems I have to forgo references and use value copies. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Comment: You should post your answer.  I was suggesting that you didn't want the constness, so to use a pointer.